# How to create to Post End Points in Next.js same file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

i want to create two `POST HTTP` end points in same file in `nextjs 13` one Post end point for creating a user an second End points for Getting  a single user. is it possible to create two same HTTP endpoints in same file..

```
// Create a New User
export async function POST(request, query) {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
  const json = await request.json()
  const collection = db.collection("users")
  const result = await collection.insertOne(json)
  return NextResponse.json(json)
}

// Get a Single user by user ID
export async function POST(request, query) {
  return NextResponse.json({ user: "get user by id " })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create two HTTP endpoints with the same name (POST) and signature (request, query) in the same file. When you define two functions with the same name and signature, the second one will override the first one and you will only have one HTTP endpoint in your code.

To fix this, you have to use different names for your functions or use different HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc) for your endpoints. Here's an example of how you could modify your code to achieve expect result:

```
    // Create a New User
    export async function createUser(request, query) {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
    const json = await request.json()
    const collection = db.collection("users")
    const result = await collection.insertOne(json)
    return NextResponse.json(json)
    }
    
    // Get a Single user by user ID
    export async function getUser(request, query) {
    return NextResponse.json({ user: "get user by id " })
    }
```